# Above shows the error no matter what I upload

Tags: php, html

When I upload files to the website so that it will not accept my files that are uploaded to the site!

the problem is that it says "**error**" every time I try to upload an image to the server.

what I want it to do is to only take png, jpg and jpeg files of types of images.

The image is only **105 KB**

and i have

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

on my form

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["TYupdater2"]))
{
    $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        echo "Are now upload to server.";
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <div id="error">Error!</div>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="bruger-info" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="90%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
        <td>Billede</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" id="uploadimg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="TYupdater2" class="click kliknu" value="Upload"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $mitpanelimg = $mebe->mitpanelimg();//Upload picture here //uploader billedet her
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You should consider breaking up your if statement to be multiple blocks. Not only will this help readability, but you can more concisely define the exact error going on.

Comment: Um... [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) is located where?

Comment: echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]; ...emmm...before the if ??

Comment: @Fred-ii- I add more code to find the error perhaps?

Comment: @RobertRozas It comes up and says image/jpeg

Comment: @user3117284 I think your issue lies in the filesize limit. You have specified 20,000, which is in BYTES; aka 20KB.

Comment: I don't quite get what it is you're trying to do. Plus what `Demonslay335` said makes sense.

Comment: Did you try to var_dump($FILES) and see whats in the array?

Comment: @Thanu its say **NULL**

Comment: @Thanu means `$_FILES`

Comment: `array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(53) "180748_1833674008170_1430011906_2049433_2632838_n.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpKoLf24" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(108333) } }`

Code its here after i say var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: Ok then... now try just having `if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"){` in the if condition and see whats the result...

Comment: The filesize is too big.

Comment: If that works then add the next `($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)` in  a new if statement within the above if statement.. and so on.. this way you'll be able to see where you get the error...

Comment: @Thanu Its work now!!! WooooW nice and thanks for it FAST HELP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is just the file size check.

As said on the manual:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['size']
   The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.
```

So your if statement has: `($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)` which means ~20kb wich will always get false if your file is bigger than ~20Kb

You have to change this part to a bigger size, if your file is 105 KB
`($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 512000)` which means 512Kb

Answer (score 0):

This script probably effectively uploads to your server.  But, to the temp folder.  This folder is emptied when your script ends deleting your uploaded file.

you need to move_uploaded_file() your file to some where you want to save it.

Other things to think about:
How many files are being uploaded?
are there chances users might upload files with the same name?
many cameras name things like IMG0001

File uploads are scary.  Does the script fail if it has say... a .php extention?

Could I upload a php file that only has the following code in it.

I dont know if that would work or not.  By that deletes the root directory in theory.

Here is a good read for you.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Dony be afraid of the manual! without move_uploaded_file your script will never work - give it a read!

Answer (score 0):

:) Try to calculate ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000). Its < 20K. You upload image (105K).